# Info Windows are showing blank

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have this google map and everything works perfectly but the info windows are showing up as blank...

I've tried to use a `for` loop but I think I put it in the wrong place because the map just goes completely blank. I tried a `foreach` loop and the same thing happens. I also tried to move the `infowindow` variable inside the for each loop with no luck.

```
// Map variable
var map;

// Create and style the map
function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 11,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(25.7819743, -80.2006986),
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
    styles: [{"featureType":"all","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"all","elementType":"labels","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"administrative.country","elementType":"labels.text","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"},{"color":"#ff0000"}]},{"featureType":"administrative.province","elementType":"labels.text.fill","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"invert_lightness":!0},{"color":"#ffffff"}]},{"featureType":"administrative.locality","elementType":"labels.text.fill","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"lightness":"-46"},{"color":"#ffffff"}]},{"featureType":"landscape","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"color":"#d8a361"},{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"color":"#c48c46"}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"color":"#cf944b"}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"geometry.stroke","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"color":"#cf944b"}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#c48c46"}]},{"featureType":"road.local","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"road.local","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"color":"#c48c46"},{"lightness":"4"}]}]
  }
);

// Custom Icons
var iconBase = 'img/';

var icons = {
  main: {
    icon: iconBase + 'map-icon.png'
  }
};

// Icon Locations and infowindow content
var locations = [
  {
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(25.7819743, -80.2006986),
    type: 'main',
    content: 'This is a simple test'
  }, {
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(25.6543563, -80.4034173),
    type: 'main',
    content: 'This is a another test'
  }, {
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(25.7589664, -80.4495347),
    type: 'main',
    content: 'This is a just another test'
  }, {
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(25.7905606, -80.3455961),
    type: 'main',
    content: 'This is yet another simple test'
  }, {
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(25.7611357, -80.3293175),
    type: 'main',
    content: 'This is a simple test'
  }, {
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(25.8501614, -80.2520588),
    type: 'main',
    content: 'This is a simple test'
  }, {
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(25.653536, -80.3311367),
    type: 'main',
    content: 'This is a simple test'
  }
];

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: locations.content
  });

// Show all markers
locations.forEach(function(location) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location.position,
    icon: icons[location.type].icon,
    map: map
  });

  marker.addListener('click', function() {
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
});
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only one `InfoWindow`, but multiple markers, you need to set the content of the `InfoWindow` with the appropriate content for that marker.   (also, `locations.content` is undefined, `locations` is an array of objects that have a `.content` property)

```
// Show all markers
locations.forEach(function(location) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location.position,
    map: map
  });

  marker.addListener('click', function() {
      infowindow.setContent(location.content)
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/gLpabvzs/1/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
// Map variable
var map;

// Create and style the map
function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 11,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(25.7819743, -80.2006986),
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
  });

  // Icon Locations and infowindow content
  var locations = [{
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(25.7819743, -80.2006986),
    type: 'main',
    content: 'This is a simple test'
  }, {
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(25.6543563, -80.4034173),
    type: 'main',
    content: 'This is a another test'
  }, {
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(25.7589664, -80.4495347),
    type: 'main',
    content: 'This is a just another test'
  }, {
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(25.7905606, -80.3455961),
    type: 'main',
    content: 'This is yet another simple test'
  }, {
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(25.7611357, -80.3293175),
    type: 'main',
    content: 'This is a simple test'
  }, {
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(25.8501614, -80.2520588),
    type: 'main',
    content: 'This is a simple test'
  }, {
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(25.653536, -80.3311367),
    type: 'main',
    content: 'This is a simple test'
  }];

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: locations.content
  });

  // Show all markers
  locations.forEach(function(location) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location.position,
      map: map
    });

    marker.addListener('click', function() {
      infowindow.setContent(location.content)
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
  });
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap"></script>
```